# how to install a repository from github?

Tags: python, git, pip

I want to install the following github repository, yet I recieve an error. what am I doing wrong?

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/gablum/DeepHit.git
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-unpack-w7qkjzy3/DeepHit (downloaded from /tmp/pip-req-build-nmcpks7w, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-req-build-nmcpks7w
```

Answer (score 7):

To install a thing with `pip` the thing must be an installable package. [The repository](https://github.com/gablum/DeepHit) is not a Python package — it doesn't have `setup.py`, it doesn't even have `__init__.py`. It's not a package and cannot be installed.

To use it you should ask [the source](https://github.com/chl8856/DeepHit) how the code is supposed to be used. I suspect the answer will include manipulations with `PYTHONPATH` or copying the code directly into your working directory.

Answer (score -2):

To download a repository just use `git clone https://github.com/repository-name-here.git`
What you do next depends on the repository. In your case I would take a look at the documentation of the repository itself which can often be found on GitHub too.